# AMQP Recover Message with and without REQUEUE behaviour in Mule ESB

Tags: mule, amqp, mule-studio, mule-component

I'm using AMQP endpoints, If the message consumer I'm doing retry   using AMQP recover. Here my query is

Mule have given option in `AMQP Recover` with Requeue = true or Requeue = false. But in rabbit doc they have strongly said Recover with Requeue= false is not supported http://www.rabbitmq.com/specification.html. Could anyone can explain what with and without requeue option happen in Mule.

Also I have tried AMQP recover with and without requeue option.Put one message in inbount queue and tested

1.Recover alone with requeue option enabled - If consumer is down , it tries to retry as expected. But as soon as Consumer service is up. There are 2 message being hit ( instead of single hit).Not sure why?

2.Recover alone without requeue option enabled - As expected, it tries to do retry,when the service is up. One message being hit( It is correct).

So I thought to use Recover without requeue- Some other time I'm also getting exception since requeue is set to false

```
  caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; reason: {#method<connection.close>(reply-code=540, reply-text=NOT_IMPLEMENTED - requeue=false, class-id=60, method-id=110), null, ""}.
```

It is due to since I kept `reply-text=NOT_IMPLEMENTED - requeue=false`. If that is the case why Mule have given as requeue as `Optional`. I got nicely confused. Could anyone help me on clearing the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an **AMQP** transport for Mule, not a **RabbitMQ** specific one.

So you have to check that the AMQP features you are using are available in the particular AMQP broker you are using.